# video trace file extracting

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing, h.264

I have mp4 video files and I need to extract some features from these videos using header information such as macroblock size, motion vector,... I need to extract video complexity features obtained by fast one-pass analysis of the chunk with an encoder (i.e., encoder pass-log). but I do not know how can I find an encoder pass-log:(